# Why does Meteor template helper not return variable in context?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

For some reason, this doesn't work at all.

`{{user_slugged username}}`

The `{{username}}` is a variable available to the template. However, it gives me a null / undefined value in the helper.

Here is my helper code

```
UI.registerHelper('user_slugged', function(username) {

... other stuff... return things.


}
```

The issue I am having is when I try something like this `{{user_slugged 'Hello'}}` it does everything right and returns what is expected.

However, when I try `{{user_slugged username}}` it doesn't seem to work even though I can easily display `{{username}}` in that same line of code.

Which seems really odd, now I'm thinking the way to send parameters to handlebars helpers might have changed in `Meteor 0.8.0`. If so, it'd be great if someone could point me into the right direction or give me an answer to this question.

EDIT: To clarify I am able to use `{{username}}` in the same line as `{{user_slugged username}}` so something like this works

`<a href="{{user_slugged username}}">{{username}}</a>`

`username` is an object property that is available in the template and at the point where I am trying to send it in as a param to the helper.

Comment: If you just use `{{username}}` in the template at that exact location, it works (shows something other than `null/undefined`)? Could it be that you are accidentally changing the _context_ around the `user_slugged` call?

Comment: I'm using username in the exact same line without any template context change

Comment: @user1952811 is `username` a property on an object or helper itself?

Comment: It's a property of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why this is happening (maybe there is a global helper `username`?), but you should be able to fix it easily by writing

```
{{user_slugged ./username}}
```

instead of

```
{{user_slugged username}}
```

The dot always means the current data context, so there is no way that the rendering engine will get confused about it.